# I could not understand a function for the ManyToMany field listing in Django

Tags: python, django

Non of the similar questions auto listed answer my question:

I have the **models.py** as follows:

````
```from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.address})'


class Participant(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
  
class Meetup(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} - {self.slug} - {self.description}'```
````

In order to be able to list the two emails I entered via the Admin panel I had the following **Admin.py**

````
```from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Meetup, Location, Participant
# Register your models here.

class MeetupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'description', 'location', 'get_emails')

    def get_emails(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([p.email for p in obj.participants.all()])

    list_filter = ('title', 'description')

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title', )}

    search_fields = ('title', )


admin.site.register(Meetup, MeetupAdmin)
admin.site.register(Location)
admin.site.register(Participant)```
````

Without using the function

````
            return "\n".join([p.email for p in obj.participants.all()])```

I would not have been able to list the two emails represented by the ManyToMany relation 

My question here is: I would like to understand what does the p and obj here. I would be so grateful if someone could explain how this work.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of a method in the `list_display`, in that case for each record the `ModelAdmin` will show, it will call the function with `obj` the object for which it wants to render the content.

Here `obj` is thus a `Meetup` object, and you can access a `ManyToManyField` so `obj.participants.all()` will return all `Participant`s that are linked to that `Meetup`. We here use list comprehension to produce a list of the `.email`s of the linked `Participant`s, and then use `'\n'.join(…)` to create a single string where we separate the email addresses with new lines (`'\n'`).

This is however *not* very efficient: if the number of `Meetup`s will grow, this will result in a lot of queries. You can select all related `Participant`s in *one* extra query with:

```
class MeetupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'description', 'location', 'get_emails')
    list_filter = ('title', 'description')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    search_fields = ('title',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('participants')

    def get_emails(self, obj):
        return '\n'.join([p.email for p in obj.participants.all()])
```

Comment: Ok fine, very good explanation. But what about the p here.

Comment: @Sarmad: that's the enumerator in the list comprehension. it thus constructs a list where `p` eventually takes each `Participant` and we add `.p.email` to the list.

Comment: @Sarmad: see https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/

Comment: When we call the function (get_emails) in the list_play statement, you may note the two arguments (self, and obj) in the beginning of your reply you said this is a Meetup object, would you explain how is this.

Comment: @Sarmad: `self` is just a reference to the `ModelAdmin` object, just as with any method. The function is called with the object `obj` in the render pipeline of the `changelist`.

Comment: This gives me excellent understanding